# Update query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update my table with the following code .But updation was not successful.

```
 $sql_edit = "UPDATE subscription SET name=?,email=? WHERE name=? & email=?";
        $q_edit = $pdo->prepare($sql_edit);
        $q_edit->execute(array($_POST['new_name'],$_POST['new_email'],$_POST['old_name'],$_POST['old_email']));
```

Comment: Check with print_r($pdo->errorInfo());,find the error

Comment: [SQL 101](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/non-typed-operators.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `AND` in `WHERE` condition instead of `&` as `&` is BITWISE operator

```
    $sql_edit = "UPDATE subscription SET name=?,email=? WHERE name=? AND email=?";
    $q_edit = $pdo->prepare($sql_edit);
    $q_edit->execute(array($_POST['new_name'],$_POST['new_email'],$_POST['old_name'],$_POST['old_email']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is because one of your $_POST variables was not set.  The code below checks that the post variables are set and if not sets them to a value of `null`.  I've changed the ampersand that you used, it should be **AND**.

```
$sql_edit = "UPDATE subscription SET name=?,email=? WHERE name=? AND email=?";
        $q_edit = $pdo->prepare($sql_edit);
        $do_update = $q_edit->execute(array(
            (isset($_POST['new_name']) ? $_POST['new_name'] : null),
            (isset($_POST['new_email']) ? $_POST['new_email'] : null),
            (isset($_POST['old_name']) ? $_POST['old_name'] : null),
            (isset($_POST['old_email']) ? $_POST['old_email'] : null)
        ));

// Also check that it was executes successfully in your code
if (!$do_update)
{
echo "Failed to update";
}
else
{
echo "Update successful";
}
```

I'd recommend checking the values before you post them, rather than just putting them into the array like that though.

One other thing to check is that your connection is not set to implicit transactions, else you will need to commit the changes to the database (or roll them back):

```
$pdo->rollBack();

$pdo->commit();
```

**This will only work if your columns are set to allow null values.**